# Spring Data Elasticsearch requires property named id

Tags: spring, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I started to work with Spring Data Elasticsearch and find issue. 
During run test which is calling findAll() through repository I am getting:

```
No id property found for class com.example.domain.entity.Project!
```

When I add field `@Transient private Long id;` in my Project entity then I am able to retrieve results correctly. But I do not want to add this field because I have already defined primary key named `projectId`. There is annotation `@Id` for that field also, so why my field `projectId` is not treated as ID? It looks like `@Id` annotation is not working for spring-data-elasticsearch, is it possible?

What should I do to avoid adding transient `id` field to my entity? It is more like workaround than solution...

Project class:

```
@Entity
@Document(indexName = "project_list", type = "external")
public class Project implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "PROJECT_ID_GENERATOR", sequenceName = "PROJECT_SEQ", initialValue = 100, allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "PROJECT_ID_GENERATOR")
    @Column(name = "PROJECT_ID")
    private Long projectId;

    .... other fields and getters/setters
}
```

Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface EsProjectRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<Project, Long> {

    List<Project> findByName(String name);
}
```

Test:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath*:test-es-context.xml" })
public class ProjectRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private EsProjectRepository esProjectRepository;

    @Test
    public void shouldGetAllDocuments() {
        // when
        Iterable<Project> actuals = esProjectRepository.findAll();
        // then
        assertThat(actuals).isNotEmpty();
    }
}
```

Configuration (test-es-context.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:elasticsearch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/elasticsearch"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/elasticsearch http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/elasticsearch/spring-elasticsearch.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:test.properties" />

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.example.domain.entity, com.example.elasticsearch.*" />

    <elasticsearch:repositories base-package="com.example.elasticsearch.repository" />

    <elasticsearch:transport-client id="client" cluster-name="${es.cluster}" cluster-nodes="${es.host}:${es.port}" />

    <bean name="elasticsearchTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchTemplate">
        <constructor-arg name="client" ref="client"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Comment: can you confirm @Id is from org.springframework.data.annotation.Id ?

Comment: I am using `@Id` from javax.persistence.Id; I agree that using additional `@Id` from org.springframework solve the issue but still is needed to have both annotations form javax and spring because I am using it on my general model.

Answer (score 4):

Use this Code and in the import statement use the other Id class import

```
@Entity
@Document(indexName = "project_list", type = "external")
public class Project implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @org.springframework.data.annotation.Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "PROJECT_ID_GENERATOR", sequenceName = "PROJECT_SEQ", initialValue = 100, allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "PROJECT_ID_GENERATOR")
    @Column(name = "PROJECT_ID")
    private Long projectId;

    .... other fields and getters/setters
}
```

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

We had similar issues.  While it might not be a perfect match with what you are trying to do, I did arrive at this question in SO, so this might help others as well.

```
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;

@Id
private String _id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
```