# how to fix Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No id property found for class com.moniesta.manufactoring.domain.Price

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a microservice with one entity called price, in this entity I only want to have one field called amount no id. It was generated automatically and I deleted it from everywhere. And updated liquibase changelogs to generate the new Database. But when I am trying to start my application, I am getting this error:

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No id property found for class com.moniesta.manufactoring.domain.Price!

I double checked my price class and I did annotate my amount field as my id in order for it to be my primary key. but still I am getting this error, and I can not seem to find the reason.

this is the class which gives the error:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "price")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
@org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.Document(indexName = "price")
public class Price implements Serializable {



    @NotNull
    @Id
    @Column(name = "price_amount", precision = 21, scale = 2)
    private BigDecimal amount;

    @ManyToMany
    private Set<Material> material = new HashSet<>();

    @ManyToMany
    private Set<MaterialSeller> materialSeller = new HashSet<>();

    // jhipster-needle-entity-add-field - JHipster will add fields here

    public BigDecimal getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public Price amount(BigDecimal amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
        return this;
    }

    public Set<Material> getMaterial() {
        return material;
    }

    public Set<MaterialSeller> getMaterialSeller() {
        return materialSeller;
    }

    public void setAmount(BigDecimal amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }
    // jhipster-needle-entity-add-getters-setters - JHipster will add getters and setters here

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) {
            return true;
        }
        if (!(o instanceof Price)) {
            return false;
        }
        return amount != null && amount.equals(((Price) o).amount);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return 31;
    }

    // prettier-ignore
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Price{" +
            ", amount=" + getAmount() +
            "}";
    }
}
```

This is the error log:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'priceService' defined in file [/home/hasan-toraman/Desktop/Moniesta-Admin/moniesta-manufactoring/target/classes/com/moniesta/manufactoring/service/PriceService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 2; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'priceSearchRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No id property found for class com.moniesta.manufactoring.domain.Price!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:798)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1358)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1204)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:895)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at com.moniesta.manufactoring.MoniestamanufactoringApp.main(MoniestamanufactoringApp.java:63)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'priceSearchRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No id property found for class com.moniesta.manufactoring.domain.Price!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1796)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1226)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:885)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:789)
    ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No id property found for class com.moniesta.manufactoring.domain.Price!
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:198)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.ElasticsearchEntityInformationCreatorImpl.getEntityInformation(ElasticsearchEntityInformationCreatorImpl.java:52)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.ElasticsearchRepositoryFactory.getEntityInformation(ElasticsearchRepositoryFactory.java:67)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.ElasticsearchRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(ElasticsearchRepositoryFactory.java:72)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:312)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:297)
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:212)
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:94)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:300)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.ElasticsearchRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(ElasticsearchRepositoryFactoryBean.java:67)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1855)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1792)
    ... 33 common frames omitted
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36069156/681929

Answer (score 1):

@Id marks a property as primary key and primary key has not null constraint by default so no need to write it explicitly and try using one of these 2 :

```
@Id
@org.springframework.data.annotation.Id
@Column(name = "price_amount", precision = 21, scale = 2)
private BigDecimal amount;
```

or

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "price_amount", precision = 21, scale = 2)
private BigDecimal amount;
```

Let me know if this helps

Comment: Would give +2 if I could - the @org.springframework.data.annotation.Id was required.